# convert rss feed into real time email

Tags: wordpress, email, websub

Hi 
Is there any way i can my rss feeds on my blog be emailed in real time.
or better yet is there a wordpress plugin that does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok solved it myself, run the pubsubhubhub plugin and use blogtrottr.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [RSS-to-Email feature of MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/). I'm not affiliated with them but do get credit when people sign up using [this referral link](http://mailchimp.com/monkey-rewards/?aid=3af1cb386b285381d5b04cfa5&afl=1).